# VS 2015 Error when using nested lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, lambda

Here is a toned down version of my use case which compiles fine on gcc 4.9.3 and clang 3.7 but fails on VS 2015 Update 2.

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include<memory>

namespace A {
    using handle = std::function<void(std::string)>;
    void func(std::string, handle) {
    }
}

class B : public std::enable_shared_from_this<B> {

public:
    void func();
};

void B::func()
{
     auto && cast = std::static_pointer_cast<B>(shared_from_this());

     auto const another_variable = [cast]() -> void 
     {
        A::func("hello", [&cast](std::string){ } );
     };
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the errors that I get

```
Error(s):
source_file.cpp(23): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'const std::shared_ptr<_Ty>' to 'B::func::<lambda_4a58826445f3685613b078cf10fc9f7e>::()::<lambda_8290a9c207487c2dc2e26a5b929b4850>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=B
        ]
source_file.cpp(23): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
source_file.cpp(23): error C2660: 'A::func': function does not take 1 arguments
```

Interestingly, it compiles fine on VS 2013 as well. Am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: Apparently only triggered when you capture by reference a captured-by-value rvalue reference: `void f() { int&& x = 1; [x] { [&x]{}; }; }`. Bug? Yes. Surprising that they didn't find it? No.

Comment: The simplest fix is probably dropping the `&&` in `auto&&`, which is gratuitous anyway due to RVO.